# Inventory is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, applet

OK so my applet is not compiling and I Googled some answers and none worked. (Such as taking public out of public class)...

Here's my code: http://www.so.pastebin.com/MBjZGneg

Heere is my error:

C:\Users\Dan\Documents\DanJavaGen\Inventory.java:12: Inventory is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener
public class Inventory extends Applet implements KeyListener  {

... help? :) please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means what it says.  You are not implementing the [keyReleased](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29) method.  You're also not implementing [keyTyped](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyTyped%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29).  If you want to keep your current class structure, you can add empty methods:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){} // ignore
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){} // ignore
```

If you put the listener in a separate (possibly inner) class, you could extend [KeyAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html), which provides these empty methods for you.

Comment: Well now I added keyRelased... and I get "Inventory is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener"..
Isn't there a way I can make it so it doesn't need all of them inside the code and have the ones I Just need?

Comment: Yes, you can use KeyAdapter.  However, one class can not extend both KeyAdapter and Applet so you would need to add a new class.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you need to override the Method "KeyReleased" in your Inventory class. I can't locate such one in your class.

Simply add it to your class and add behavior